# R: extract list of matching parts of a string via regex

Tags: regex, r, string, substring, string-matching

Let's say that I need to extract different parts from a string as list, for example I would like to divide the string `"aaa12xxx"` in three parts.

One possibility is to do three `gsub` calls:

```
parts = c()
parts[1] = gsub('([[:alpha:]]+)([0-9]+)([[:alpha:]]+)', '\\1', "aaa12xxx")
parts[2] = gsub('([[:alpha:]]+)([0-9]+)([[:alpha:]]+)', '\\2', "aaa12xxx")
parts[3] = gsub('([[:alpha:]]+)([0-9]+)([[:alpha:]]+)', '\\3', "aaa12xxx")
```

Of course this seems quite a waste (even if it's inside a `for` loop). Isn't there a function that simply returns the list of parts from a regex and a test string?

Answer (score 4):

Just split the input string through  `strsplit` and get the parts you want..

```
> x <- "aaa12xxx"
> strsplit(x,"(?<=[[:alpha:]])(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=[[:alpha:]])", perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "aaa" "12"  "xxx"
```

Get the parts by specifying the index number..

```
> m <- unlist(strsplit(x,"(?<=[[:alpha:]])(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=[[:alpha:]])", perl=TRUE))
> m[1]
[1] "aaa"
> m[2]
[1] "12"
> m[3]
[1] "xxx"
```

- `(?<=[[:alpha:]])(?=\\d)` Matches  all the boundaries which are preceded by an alphabet and followed by a digit.
- `|` OR
- `(?<=\\d)(?=[[:alpha:]])` Matches  all the boundaries which are preceded by a digit and followed by an alphabet.
- Splitting your input according to the matched boundaries will give you the desired output.

Comment: but the perl option is related only at your regex format, I mean, it's not mandatory, right?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I would suggest you `unlist(m)` and then just index it is as it was a normal atomic vector, rather than using double index each time.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: why do you think it's mandatory? It's just how the regex format that he decided. I could have used another format to reach the same result, I think

Comment: @asb, you can decide on any regex you want. Like almost any problem can be solved using different methods. I meant that this solution is using base R operations and there is no problem using `perl = TRUE` as this an argument argument within `gsub`. Also, you can't do lookbehind without `perl = TRUE`.

Answer (score 3):

```
(\\d+)|([a-zA-Z]+)
```

or

```
([[:alpha:]]+)|([0-9]+)
```

You can just grab the capture.use `str_match_all()` from `library(stringr)`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/8